# How to fix the invalid name in the ssl certificate?

Tags: security, ssl, certificate, openssl

I generated ssl certificate with:

```
openssl genrsa -out key.pem 2048
openssl req -new -sha256 -key key.pem -out csr.csr
openssl req -x509 -sha256 -days 12775 -key key.pem -in csr.csr -out certificate.pem
```

but after checking my openssl server with ssllab I got the following invalid message:
[image]

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and add the results of `openssl req -noout -text -in csr.csr`.  This will show a text version of the csr generated in step 2.

Comment: Set a value to `issuerAltName` [Provide subjectAltName to openssl directly on command line](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74345/provide-subjectaltname-to-openssl-directly-on-command-line)

Comment: Cross posted as: https://serverfault.com/questions/886746/how-to-fix-the-invalid-name-in-the-ssl-certificate

Comment: Ramhound's link is good, but it needs to be `subjectAltName`, _not_ issuerAltName.